# Cosine similarity between two dictionary's values

Tags: python, class, dictionary, tfidfvectorizer, latent-semantic-indexing

I have this dict called `queries`:

```py
{'q1': ['similar',
  'law',
  'must',
  'obey',
  'construct',
  'aeroelast',
  'model',
  'heat',
  'high',
  'speed',
  'aircraft'],
 'q2': ['structur',
  'aeroelast',
  'problem',
  'associ',
  'flight',
  'high',
  'speed',
  'aircraft'],
 'q3': ['problem', 'heat', 'conduct', 'composit', 'slab', 'solv', 'far']
...
}
```

And have used this code to transform it into a dict of vectorized arrays:

```py
class RetrievalSystem:
    def __init__(self, docs, num_concepts, min_df=1, alpha=1.0, beta=0.75, gamma=0.15):
        # create a doc-term matrix out of our doc collection
        self.vec = TfidfVectorizer(tokenizer=str.split, min_df=min_df)
        doc_term_mat = self.vec.fit_transform([" ".join(docs[doc_id]) for doc_id in docs])
        self.q_vecs = dict() # query vectors
        
        self.svd = TruncatedSVD(n_components = num_concepts, random_state = 42)
        
        self.doc_vecs = self.svd.fit_transform(doc_term_mat)

    def retrieve_n_rank_docs(self, queries, max_docs=-1):
       
        for query in queries:
            s = self.vec.transform([" ".join(queries[query])])
            s = self.svd.transform(s)
            if query not in self.q_vecs.keys():
                self.q_vecs[query] = s
```

The `max_docs` arguments governs the maximum number of documents to be returned by each query. And now `self.q_vecs` looks like this:

```py
{'q217': array([[ 0.16555858,  0.12041974,  0.10034606,  0.03249144,  0.00843294,
         0.16582048, -0.20520625, -0.05597786, -0.12666519, -0.10517737,
         0.14363559, -0.01525909, -0.16574115, -0.04112081, -0.1374631 ,
         0.05047798,  0.05825697, -0.01779095, -0.05663042, -0.14333234,
        -0.09671375, -0.02205753,  0.03309577, -0.04512224, -0.01605542,
         0.00762974,  0.02407301,  0.00426722,  0.00654344,  0.08085963,
         0.08657383, -0.09913353,  0.01492773, -0.06813004, -0.01151318,
        -0.08565942,  0.03826287, -0.00330817,  0.13141591,  0.04920131,
        -0.08375895,  0.09465868, -0.03466024,  0.01838176, -0.00336209,
         0.02372735, -0.03390722,  0.0440413 ,  0.00371048,  0.09835254,
        -0.01099799,  0.0014484 ,  0.06276236,  0.04311937, -0.0867389 ,
         0.00850617,  0.00496759, -0.17198825,  0.07988587,  0.05727097,
         0.13304752,  0.08784825, -0.06141824, -0.01383098, -0.02348199,
        -0.04522944,  0.05257815,  0.08263177, -0.01140021, -0.05829286,
        -0.04885191,  0.09377792,  0.0190092 ,  0.00947696,  0.05598195,
        -0.03815088, -0.02834209,  0.0281708 , -0.02843137, -0.03210851,
         0.04751607, -0.01162277,  0.02034976, -0.02088302,  0.07665635,
         0.0195319 , -0.0157795 ,  0.01210985, -0.03183579,  0.01161029,
         0.02409737, -0.01007874,  0.10754846,  0.01010833, -0.05662593,
        -0.01729383, -0.03097083,  0.03369774,  0.00572065,  0.02632313]]), 'q99': array([[ 0.10287323, -0.01085065, -0.00967409, -0.04218846,  0.09239141,
         0.07992809, -0.00359886, -0.03796564,  0.01250241,  0.01951022,
        -0.03673524, -0.02372439, -0.03240905, -0.03081271,  0.02817431,
         0.12468386, -0.02051108,  0.12191644,  0.00624408, -0.05094331,
         0.09598166, -0.02341246, -0.0020474 , -0.05629724,  0.03516377,
         0.09028871,  0.02806492, -0.02300581, -0.02998558, -0.00270938,
         0.01611941,  0.04106955,  0.05371339, -0.02561045, -0.01916819,
         0.08158927, -0.03353019, -0.01020131, -0.03670832,  0.02845091,
         0.07133292, -0.0944471 , -0.00662414,  0.0920997 , -0.00206586,
         0.07063442, -0.00814919, -0.00374118, -0.01353651,  0.07968094,
         0.00796783, -0.01397921, -0.07712498, -0.00308536,  0.07785687,
        -0.01220938, -0.06646712,  0.04048088,  0.01321445,  0.00041508,
        -0.04644943,  0.09307773,  0.0188646 , -0.03233048, -0.04803833,
        -0.06355723, -0.00560934, -0.05478746,  0.03196071,  0.08420215,
        -0.07706163, -0.12595219, -0.01330823, -0.00079499, -0.02515943,
         0.00087481, -0.00596035,  0.01680558,  0.0138655 , -0.01290259,
        -0.0497661 , -0.04627047, -0.00239779, -0.06377815, -0.01103349,
         0.00205314, -0.0774958 ,  0.00223332, -0.00976858,  0.02365778,
         0.02600081,  0.01212485,  0.03451618,  0.00642054, -0.00025119,
         0.00898667,  0.00749051,  0.02099796, -0.00906813, -0.06770008]])
...
}
```

I'd like to take the cosine similarity between the vector representations here and those of self.docs, and then sort the documents these queries came from in descending order of the cosine similarity. So the desired output would look something like this:

```py
{
    'q217': ['d983', 'd554', ..., 'd623'],
    'q99' : ['d716', 'd67', ..., 'd164'],
    ...
}
```

I have written this code to try to output to cos similarity but it only returns 1 key-value pair:

```py
class RetrievalSystem:
    def __init__(self, docs, num_concepts, min_df=1, alpha=1.0, beta=0.75, gamma=0.15):
        self.alpha, self.beta, self.gamma = alpha, beta, gamma
        
        # create a doc-term matrix out of our doc collection
        self.vec = TfidfVectorizer(tokenizer=str.split, min_df=min_df)
        doc_term_mat = self.vec.fit_transform([" ".join(docs[doc_id]) for doc_id in docs])
        self.q_vecs = dict() # query vectors
        
        self.svd = TruncatedSVD(n_components = num_concepts, random_state = 42)
        
        self.doc_vecs = self.svd.fit_transform(doc_term_mat)
        # YOUR CODE HERE
        #raise NotImplementedError()

    def retrieve_n_rank_docs(self, queries, max_docs=-1):
       
        for query in queries:
            s = self.vec.transform([" ".join(queries[query])])
            s = self.svd.transform(s)
            if query not in self.q_vecs.keys():
                self.q_vecs[query] = s
        
            all_keys = list(self.q_vecs.keys())
            new_d = {}
        
            for i in range(len(all_keys)):
                for j in range(i+1,len(all_keys)):
                    new_d[query] = {1 - spatial.distance.cosine(self.q_vecs[all_keys[i]], self.q_vecs[all_keys[j]])}
```

Comment: ` new_d[query] =` The value of `query` is not being updated in each iteration. What is `query`?

Comment: Hey, sorry. I updated the question to reflect that the first dictionary is called `queries` so my for loop is calling each query in queries. But I see what you're saying,

Comment: I cant workout what you are trying to do, but your indentation is wrong. The value of query in your second loop is always the last key in the dictionary `Queries`

Comment: Gotcha. Basically I am trying to take the cosine similarity between the values in `self.q_vecs`

Comment: This looks like a simple python error, but there's too much other stuff going on so I can't run it. I don't think we really need all the docs and queries, but a small "working" sample to recreate your issue would be nice.

Answer (score 1):

because the code is not a minimal reproducable example, I cant fully help. But to create a dictionary of cosine similarities of every combination of keys you can do:

```
import itertools
import numpy as np


q_ves = {
    "q1": np.array([0, 1]),
    "q2": np.array([1, 0]),
    "q3": np.array([0, 2]),
    "q4": np.array([10, 10])
}
new_q = {}
for k1, k2 in list(map(dict, itertools.combinations(
    q_vecs.items(), 2))):
    new_d[(k1, k2)] = 1 - scipy.spatial.distance.cosine(q_vecs[k1], q_vecs[k2])
```

Which will give you:

```
{
    ('q1', 'q2'): -0.04468849422512422,
    ('q1', 'q3'): 1,
    ('q1', 'q4'): -0.04468849422512422,
    ('q2', 'q3'): -0.04468849422512422,
    ('q2', 'q4'): 1,
    ('q3', 'q4'): -0.04468849422512422
}
```

I hope this is what you are after, as I dont understand how you generate the strings for:

```
{
    'q217': ['d983', 'd554', ..., 'd623'],
    'q99' : ['d716', 'd67', ..., 'd164'],
    ...
}
```

Comment: Tom, I’m sorry. I worded my question wrong. Need to calculate cosine similarity between self.q_vecs and self.doc_vecs. Of course, I forgot to include docs here but they are the Cranfield collection documents.